# c# Strange service behavior

Tags: c#, .net, soap

I have noticed that every time I use a dictionary in a service that it gets converted to ArrayofKeyValueTypeType[randomchars]. My question is why is there random chars added onto the end? I understand that the root of a dictionary is an array of Key/value pairs so that part makes sense.

ex 
c# object:

```
[DataMember]
public Dictionary<WorkOrderSearchFields, string> SearchCriteria;
```

snippet from wsdl:

```
type="tns:ArrayOfKeyValueOfWorkOrderSearchFieldsstringKScFBAWF"
```

Comment: "if either the key or the value types are not primitive types, a namespace hash of the data contract namespaces of the key and value types is appended to the name. " - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/collection-types-in-data-contracts#collection-naming